# Не получается использовать векторную графику как ярлык

Tags: android, vector-drawable

В обычной ситуации это можно сделать, удалив строку `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` в `gradle` - файле. Но эта строка нужна чтоб использовать векторную графику благодаря `supportLibrary` в других местах приложения, к примеру, `ImageView`. В моем случае на API v15 вектор прекрасно отображается в `ImageView` и без сточки, но всплывает предупреждение о том, что нужна эта строка (+ использование в `XML` `srcCompat` вместо `src`, что уже есть).
Добавив ее, вместо векторного ярлыка приложение использует по умолчанию ярлык "зеленого робота".
Вопрос: как использовать вектор одновременно как ярлык и параметр для`imageView` в пределах одного приложения?

Comment: когда в ImageView "отображается без строчки" на API < 21 - студия делает растровый "заменитель" векторному изображению, то есть в этом случае у вас обычные картинки используются вместо векторных

Comment: @pavlofff о, нашел об этом
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio
спасибо большое!, напишите как ответ чтоб забрать свои баллы